# Akka persistence NotSerializableException for Enumeration

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I'm trying to use akkas persistance module(2.3.0), unfortunately when I'm sending Persistent message containing Enumeration I'm getting  `java.io.NotSerializableException`. Here's my earthy example:

```
object TestEnum extends Enumeration with Serializable {
  type TestEnum = Value
  val test = Value("test")
}

class TestProcessor extends Processor with Logging {
  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case PersistenceFailure(payload, sequenceNr, cause) =>
      log.error(s"error when reciving persistent message[$payload]", cause)
    case a =>
      log.error(s"test proc recived message [$a]")
  }
}
val a = sys.actorOf(Props[TestProcessor])
a ! Persistent(TestEnum.test)
```

this ends with

```
 error when reciving persistent message[test]java.io.NotSerializableException:         scala.slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent$MappedJdbcType$$anon$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply$mcV$sp(Serializer.scala:129)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.toBinary(Serializer.scala:129)
    at akka.persistence.serialization.MessageSerializer.persistentPayloadBuilder(MessageSerializer.scala:111)
    at akka.persistence.serialization.MessageSerializer.akka$persistence$serialization$MessageSerializer$$persistentMessageBuilder(MessageSerializer.scala:97)
    at akka.persistence.serialization.MessageSerializer.toBinary(MessageSerializer.scala:45)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:90)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:90)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.serialize(Serialization.scala:90)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.persistentToBytes(LeveldbStore.scala:98)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.persistentToBytes(LeveldbJournal.scala:19)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.akka$persistence$journal$leveldb$LeveldbStore$$addToMessageBatch(LeveldbStore.scala:104)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$$anonfun$writeMessages$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(LeveldbStore.scala:48)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$$anonfun$writeMessages$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(LeveldbStore.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$$anonfun$writeMessages$1.apply(LeveldbStore.scala:48)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$$anonfun$writeMessages$1.apply(LeveldbStore.scala:48)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.withBatch(LeveldbStore.scala:90)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.withBatch(LeveldbJournal.scala:19)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.writeMessages(LeveldbStore.scala:48)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.writeMessages(LeveldbJournal.scala:19)
    at akka.persistence.journal.SyncWriteJournal$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncWriteJournal.scala:27)
    at akka.persistence.journal.SyncWriteJournal$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$1.apply(SyncWriteJournal.scala:27)
    at akka.persistence.journal.SyncWriteJournal$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$1.apply(SyncWriteJournal.scala:27)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.persistence.journal.SyncWriteJournal$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SyncWriteJournal.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.aroundReceive(LeveldbJournal.scala:19)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

anybody has any idea what is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: You should define TestEnum as a top level class (or in a object) to avoid closing over things that are not serializable.

Answer (score 2):

It was more complicated that I thought. According to Patrik suggesstion I've defined all participating objects as top level classes/objects in different files. And test example started to work. Finally I've discovered why error occurs:

I'm using slick to communicate with my DB so I've declared very useful Enumeration base class with default mapper that allows slick to use Enumeration without writing converters

```
abstract class DBEnum extends Enumeration {
  implicit val enumMapper = MappedJdbcType.base[Value, String](_.toString, this.withName(_))
}
```

Then I've derived from that class and created

```
object AccountType extends DBEnum{
  type AccountType = Value
  val ADMINISTRATOR = Value("administrator")
  val REGULAR = Value("regular")
  val ADMINISTRATOR_SPONSORED = Value("administrator_sponsored")
}
```

my actual test example was

```
a ! Persistent(TestEnum.test)
a ! Persistent(AccountType.ADMINISTRATOR)
```

and it seems that TestEnum started to have enumMapper(probably because of some weird implicit conversion - maby someone can explain how is it possible) which can't be serialized(it does not implement serializable).

changing

```
implicit val enumMapper = MappedJdbcType.base[Value, String](_.toString, this.withName(_))
```

to

```
implicit def enumMapper = MappedJdbcType.base[Value, String](_.toString, this.withName(_))
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with a json formatter on an `Enumeration`. In order to prevent excessive object instantiation of the `enumMapper`, you can also use a `lazy val` instead of a `def`. e.g. `implicit lazy val enumMapper = ...`